# Index JSONB column in PostgreSQL for range filter on integer value in a nested dynamic key

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a `companies` table with a JSONB column called `data`
Each row in the table represents a company.

An example for JSON data of a company:

```
{
    "geographies":
    {
        "ES":
        {
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "R&D": 18,
                "Sales": 10,
                "HR": 5
            },
        },
        "US":
        {
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "Sales": 4
            }
        },
        "DE":
        {
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "Product": 1
            }
        },
        "FR":
        {
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "R&D": 18,
                "HR": 2
            },
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```

My final goal is to filter (as quickly as possible using indexes) for companies with the following conditions:

1. Have more than X sales person in a specific country (i.e. geographies.US.departmentDistribution.Sales > X)
2. Have less then X HR person in any country (i.e. geographies.*.departmentDistribution.HR < X)

It is important to note three things:

1. The country codes are dynamic and are not a predefined list (I don't know which company will have data for which country)
2. Some countries will appear almost in all companies in the table so that filtering first for a specific country using a GIN Index and then do a sequential scan on the ranged value of a specific department won't be very efficient
3. The departments are predefined so that I can create multiple indexes, one per department if needed

I've researched quite a lot and couldn't find an explanation how I can achieve such index on the department values, but I'm quite certain that there is a way to achieve that (maybe using some functions such as jsonb_each or something similar)

BTW, I have no problem to change the structure of the JSON to be an array based if that can help. i.e.

```
{
    "geographies":
    [
        {
            "countryCode": "ES",
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "R&D": 18,
                "Sales": 10,
                "HR": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "countryCode": "US",
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "Sales": 4
            }   
        },
        {
            "countryCode": "DE",
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "Product": 1
            }   
        },
        {
            "countryCode": "FR",
            "departmentDistribution":
            {
                "R&D": 18,
                "HR": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your two example queries are quite different from each other.  I don't think there is a general way to index those effectively with the current data structure.  You would need to unnest (at least one) level, so you have a company_geography table.  Then you could create a separate index for each department.  If that doesn't work out for you, maybe you should focus more on parallelization than indexing.

Comment: Seems fair enough. I will come up with something and update if it works and how